# Tiny Operating System in MASM

Tags: operating-system, masm, bootloader, bootstrapping

Hi all I'm looking for a way to create a very small subset of an Operating System in Microsoft Macro Assembler(MASM). Preferably a system that can at basic boot a standard pc and give a directory listing; any resource or advice that can point me in the right direction will be welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many resources just by typing in google, but would recomment a higher level language.  But if your goal is writting in assembly than MASM should still not be your choice. MASM's EULA says it cannot be used for anything other than writing for Windows. There are reasons beyond that. Check out FASM.  There is an OS written entire in FASM

The below link has MANY links inside of it. 
 [OS Construction Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=3164)

Comment: If he is looking to make the bootstrap in assembly as well then at least a small part of it would have to be written in asm

Answer (score 1):

I think [Operating Systems Design and Implementation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131429388) could satisfy most of your questions, what I don't really know if MASM is the compiler chosen for low level parts. Most of the code however is C based with an small percent of asm. However, directory listing depends on the filesystem you want to read from so, that's something else, but it's covered there too.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that in *assembler* (and not in C, or C++, etc...)?

There are lot of tiny free software operating systems already. You could look at some of them (e.g. on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net)).

And today's PCs are a bit more complex than what they where ten years ago. For instance, today's keyboards and mices are often USB devices, so you often need to have an USB subsystem in your operating system kernel, just to be able to read from a keyboard.

I think that studing existing free operating systems kernel, and/or contribute to them will probably teach you more, and might be more fun.